# NoneType object has no attribute 'text'?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the infobox for a number of artist wikipedias.  But I keep on getting the no attribute error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url= "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles"

page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', class_='infobox vcard plainlist')
result = {}
exceptional_row_count = 0
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    if tr.find('th'):
        result[tr.find('th').text] = tr.find('td').text
    else:
        exceptional_row_count += 1
if exceptional_row_count > 1:
    print ('WARNING ExceptionalRow>1: ', table)
print (result)
```

The error is in this line:

```
---> 13         result[tr.find('th').text] = tr.find('td').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: So `tr.find('td')` produced `None` (since you did test `tr.find('th')` first).

Comment: `result[tr.find('th').text] = tr.find('td').text if tr.find('td') else None`